# Proof: Each common divisor c of a,b divides GCD(a,b)

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, alternative-proof, prime-factorization

there already exists a proof for this theorem: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Common_Divisor_Divides_GCD

This one, however, uses Bêzout's Identity. I'm not allowed to use this for the proof.

So, I had two ideas:

(1) Use prime factorization (and here, I believe, I am not sure to use this, since it'll appear in later lesson - however, let's try this one as well!)

So let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ non-negative. 
Let $a=\displaystyle\prod_{i}{p_i}^{\alpha_i}$ and $b=\displaystyle\prod_i{p_i}^{\beta_i}$, then $\gcd(a,b)$ will contain the exponents $\min(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$.

And what next?

(2) Let now $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ non-negative with $d = gcd(a,b)$.
If now c is a common divisor of both a and b, I'll get:

$a = c^n \cdot p, b = c^n \cdot q$ for $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

If $c$ or $c^n$ is the GCD, then it divides itself, which seems clear to me.
If neither $c$ nor $c^n$ is the GCD, then.. ? Yes, what then?

I'll appreciate any comments ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Next, consider any common divisor $c$, and make a note about how the exponents in its prime factorization compare to min$(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$.

(2) From here, consider what would happen if the greatest common divisor could not be written in the form $c^nr$. You can arrive at a contradiction by using the definition of gcd.

Comment: (1)So  for  $c=\displaystyle\prod_{i}{p_i}^{c_i}$  the exponent $c_i \le min(\alpha_i , \beta_i)$ for any $i$ ? And since the GCD(a,b) contains all the prime numbers that c contains, this means c|d ?

Comment: That's correct. You probably want to be a bit more precise in your language when you talk about numbers "containing" numbers, but you have exactly the correct idea. (You can be more precise in this way: Since min$(\alpha_i, \beta_i) - c_i$ is always non-negative, you can show explicitly that the result of the division  will be an integer).

Comment: thank you very much! I know that I'm not always precise enough, I think it's due to my bad english language knowledge ;( One last question to way (2): If GCD(a,b) could not be written in the form $c^nr$, then.. I cannot conclude with a contradiction as you've mentioned above. I'd be glad if you can help me once more

Comment: Actually I think the conclusion I had in mind would implicitly use the first proof. Better to stick with that one.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:**

What will follow, is similar to your first approach, however, it is formulated using slightly different words, to emphasize some parallels, which you might find helpful in the future.

**Hint:**

- There is an intuition which treats numbers as [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) or vectors where the coordinates are indexed by prime numbers and the values are the exponents in the factorization. For example, the prime factorization of $63 = 3\cdot3\cdot7$ would give you multiset $\{3\to2,7\to1\}$ (all the rest gets zero) or an infinite vector $(0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$.
- With such an interpretation there are multiple parallels:
  $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  \textbf{operation} & \textbf{multiset analog} & \textbf{vector analog} \\\hline
  \text{multiplication} & \cup & + \\
  \text{division} & \setminus & - \\
  \text{divisibility} & \subseteq & \leq \\
  \gcd & \cap & \min
  \end{array}$$
- What is important, the operators listed above treat the coordinates independently! That simplifies your problem to prove:
  $$c_p \leq a_p\ \ \land\ \ c_p \leq b_p\quad \implies\quad c_p \leq \min(a_p, b_p).$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$